# How can I access DOM elements in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, properties

I am tetsing a template driven form in angular, just testing not validating it.
I have read that it can be done using a viewChild property but it seems to not work for me.

I create a reference like this in my one of my forms label:

```
<label #ref  id=.. class=...>
```

And now in my component I do this:

```
@ViewChild('ref') ref:ElementRef;
```

So, I suppose I created a valiable of type ElementRef that is  viewChild of my input. So now I can use **ref** in my tests.

Inside my tests I do this:

```html
let ref: HTMLElement:

it(....=>
{
ref = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ref')).nativeElement;
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(ref.innerHTML)toContain('Name');// or whatever
}

)
```

Now consider that the test, html and component files are separated from one another.

I still get errors of **nativeElemnt property cannot be read.**  eventhough I have imported ElemntRef.

Is this the right way to access the DOM elemnts?? Or this viewChild doesnt make a referece to my label??

And again can I use the ID to access the form elements? What I have read they use a reference with #.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use `elementRef` to access the native element.

Comment: Post your answer and I will vote it if it works for me

Comment: In my experience you don't use the unit tests to validate that the DOM is displaying the correct values. Your test should validate that your component is setting the correct properties/events for itself and then use something like selenium to test that the DOM is working as you expected. if you couple them closely like this in your unit tests then any changes to the DOM/UI will cause you to edit a lot of your tests.

Comment: Again I do not need validation of teh form. Just to test that a element exists, an input for example. That it sends the correct data. How can I access it???

Answer (score 8):

**For direct access to DOM in Angular you can make *judicious* use of [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef)**

> However Direct access to DOM elements is not a good practice because
>   it leaves you vulnerable to XSS attacks.

---

### Your AppComponent

```
import {Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
export class AppComponent implements ngOnInit {

constructor(private _elementRef : ElementRef) { }

ngOnInit(): void
{
  this.ModifyDOMElement();
}

 ModifyDOMElement() : void
 { 
   //Do whatever you wish with the DOM element.
   let domElement = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`#someID`);
 } 
}
```

### Your HTML

```
<p id="someID"></p>
```

Comment: And how to access it on a test class??

Comment: Just import `ElementRef` by `import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';` in your test class and inject it into the constructor like `constructor(private _elementRef : ElementRef) { }`.

Comment: In my testing class that is a different file from my appcomponnet I should do this: it().... expect (comp.domElement)toContain(...)?

Comment: Have you tried importing `ElementRef` in your test class?

Comment: Yes I imported it. NOW HOW CAN i TEST IT? What you showed to me is how to access it in my appComponent

Comment: You can do the same in your unit test for what I showed in the app component, where you get access to the complete DOM element.

Comment: domElement in thi case is an HTMLEelemnt??

Comment: Yes its a `HTMLElement` type

Comment: Heyy! Thanks my friend, but when I print in the test class console.log(comp.domElement) it gives me undefined.                                     I have previously in my test class:                                                                          
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(JhiLoginModalComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;